# sed: How to back reference one instance of sequence

Tags: regex, bash, powershell, sed, regex-group

I have input as sequence of floating points:

`0.44491    0.068512   0.00086731 0.19827    0.10896    0.00021067`

Now I wrote the regex as `'s/\(\([[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+\)\{6\}/\2/p'`.
I was wondering how can refer to second instance in this sequence so it would match `0.068512`?

With powershell I am able to accomplish this as:

`$ (gc $file | sls "(([0-9]+.[0-9]+)\s+){6}" -AllMatches).Matches.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value }`

So I am looking for equivalent of "Captures[1]" in sed.

Comment: There is no such equivalent in sed. Capture collection is a very rare feature in regex only available out of the box in .NET and PyPi regex libraries.

Comment: Sad to hear. Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: I don't have a machine with perl on it in front of me right now and it has been like 10 years since I touched perl but I thought the captures could be accessed via number variables. For instance I thought $1 was the whole capture then $2 was the first sub or some such. Like I say, it has been a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, you can try

```
var=1;echo '0.44491    0.068512   0.00086731 0.19827    0.10896    0.00021067' | sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*){'"$var"'}([^[:blank:]]*).*/\2/'
```

var=1 to catch the second

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk '{print $2}' filename`.

A little explanation about `awk` can be found [here](https://superuser.com/a/603601).